# В чем ошибка, почему не происходит остановка процесса

Tags: python

```
import datetime
b = datetime.datetime.today().strftime(input())
a = datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
while b!=a:
    print("no")
else:
    print(b)
```

В b я ввожу время которое мне нужно, например 15:00:00, в a находится текущее время, например 14:59:00. По идее пока b не равен a, должно печататься "no", а когда они совпадут, то процесс должен завершиться и выдать b, но продолжается печататься "no". В чем ошибка?

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать так (использую `time` вместо `datetime` поскольку использование `datetime` - лишнее) :

```py
import time

time_to_off = time.strptime(input(), "%H:%M:%S")

while time_to_off != time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"):
    print("no")
else:
    print(b)
```